# How to fix ts-node running issue

Tags: typescript

I ran ts file with ts-node index.ts
It works well on my computer
but it occurs error on remote server like this:

> TypeError: Unable to require file: server/server.ts
>   This is usually the result of a faulty configuration or import. Make sure there is a `.js`, `.json` or other executable extension with loader attached before `ts-node` available.

I imported Server class like this
`import Server from './server/server';`
I am not sure what is wrong

Comment: Could you provide some more detail (code, file structure, etc)? It could be that you compiled the TypeScript locally with ```tsc```, but not on the remote machine?

Comment: Don't you have both `server.js` and `server.ts` files by any chance (like accidential usage of tsc)? In such case ts-node wouldn't know which `server` file it should import

Comment: Hi, ThaFog
Thanks for your reply
No, I have only server.ts file